# How can we make cbt commands rerunnable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have to save the cbt scripts in rerunnable format . Do we have support for this in bigtable.

cbt createtable mobile-time-series

Can we save the scripts in this format like we save in mysql

cbt createtable IF NOT EXISTS mobile-time-series

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `createtable` command for a table that already exists it will just provide an error saying the table exists, so you can call it on an existing table without any consequences:

```
Creating table: rpc error: code = AlreadyExists desc = Table already exists: projects/PROJECT/instances/INSTANCE/tables/TABLE
```

If you're looking to recreate the table each time you run your program you could do something like this:

```
if cbt ls mobile-time-series | grep -q "Family Name"; 
    then cbt deletetable mobile-time-series;
fi

cbt createtable mobile-time-series
```

This might not be ideal since table deletion/recreation can take some time, so you might want to append a timestamp to your table name and use that for this. Let me know if this answers your question or if you had another issue around your rerunnable script.

Comment: Yes, this does not suit my requirement . I have to save the scripts in prod environment and run it in automation jobs . Every time the job runs its verify the table is created or not  and we make it rerunnable so that script does not fail.  Do we don't have the provison of rerunnable scripts where we use exists or not exists clause

Comment: Could you clarify? I believe I provided options that would help you verify if the table is created or not. Just `ls` the table and if it returns the column families as checked via the `grep -q` then it exists.

Comment: Yes , I have a requirement where i can't delete or drop  the table but using the shell script to make it cbt rerunnable and it will be part of automation script where the jenkins job will be run . What is the optimal way to do that.

Comment: Hi @billy jacobson , I am writing this script on the basis of status code .               
cbt createtable abc
if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then
 cbt ls abc
 if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then
  status=1
  exit status 
 fi
fi       cbt createfamily abc configuration
if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then
 cbt ls abc| grep configuration
 if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then
  status=1
  exit status 
 fi
fi.                                                                                                                      
Similarly there are around 20 tables . I need to copy paste every time. is there any optimal approach

Comment: You could probably do some kind of for loop over the list of table names you want. I'm not too familiar with bash scripting but you should be able to use the commands in a loop.